# How do we solve the integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2-y}\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration

The integral to be solved is given by:

$$ I = \int \frac{1}{x^2-y}\mathrm{d}x$$

I was wondering what integral substitution I would need to make. I looked at symbolab and it directed me to use $x = u\sqrt{y}$ as a substitution, but where does it come from?

Comment: If $y$ here is a constant (wrt $x$), then the integral can be solved by partial fraction technique.

Comment: Thank You everyone for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have to make a substitution* to solve this integral. Take a look at the following if $y>0$:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-y} = \frac{1}{(x-\sqrt y)(x+\sqrt y)} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt y} \frac{(x+\sqrt y) - (x-\sqrt y)}{(x-\sqrt y)(x+\sqrt y)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt y} \left(\frac{1}{x-\sqrt y} - \frac{1}{x+\sqrt y}\right)$$
I hope you can directly the integrate this now. By the way, this is popularly known as the partial fractions technique.

If $y=0$, there is nothing to talk about. If $y<0$, you can still split the integrand as:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-y} = \frac{1}{(x-i\sqrt{-y})(x+i\sqrt{-y})}=\frac{1}{2i\sqrt{-y}} \left(\frac{1}{x-i\sqrt{-y}} - \frac{1}{x+i\sqrt{-y}}\right)$$
There is nothing special about the introduction of $i = \sqrt{-1}$, you can still integrate everything in the usual way, while keeping in mind that only the **real part** of the expression is of interest to us. The imaginary part will anyway turn out to be zero in this case.

P.S. I assumed $y$ is a constant w.r.t. $x$ because that's what we do unless otherwise specified.

Comment: You need to distinguish cases $y>0$, $y=0$, and $y<0$ and handle them separately.

Comment: This argument implicitly assumes that $y>0$.

Comment: Fixed! Please check.

Comment: Very good one, upvoted:-)

Answer (score 1):

Here, you need to regard $y$ as a constant, at least for this integral.

The right substitution really depends on the sign of $y$. If $y > 0$, then $x = u\sqrt{y}$ is appropriate. If $y < 0$, then you want $x = u \sqrt{-y}$.

The advantage of making the substitution versus what epsilon-emperor does, is that you will need to integrate a rational function, either $\frac{1}{u^2 - 1}$ or $\frac{1}{u^2 + 1}$ that has no parameters in it, rather than $\frac{1}{x^2 - y}$, which is a pain.

The answers will look different in each case. You know that the integral of $\frac{1}{u^2 + 1}$ will be an arctangent function, whereas (at least if you want to avoid inverse hyperbolic functions), you will integrate $\frac{1}{u^2 - 1}$ by partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

Epsilon-Emperor's trick is very good. Here is the solution using trigonometry substitution giving the same result (assuming y>0;if y<0, use similar  $\tan \theta$ substitution instead；if y=0, then it is trival).

$I = \int \frac{1}{x^2-y}\mathrm{d}x$

${x^2-y}=$y(($\frac{x}{\sqrt y})^2-1)$

set $\frac{x}{\sqrt y}$= $\sec\theta$,$dx=\sqrt y  $ $\sec\theta$   $\tan \theta $ d$ \theta$

$y((\frac{x}{\sqrt y})^2-1)$ = $y\tan\theta ^2$,

$I = \int \frac{1}{y\tan\theta ^2}\sqrt y  $ $\sec\theta$   $\tan \theta$ d$ \theta$

=$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt y\tan\theta}  $ $\sec\theta$ d$ \theta$

=$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt y}  $ $\csc\theta$ d$ \theta$

=$\frac{1}{\sqrt y} $$ln|\csc\theta$-$\cot\theta$|+C

= $\frac{1}{2\sqrt y}$ $ln|\frac{x-\sqrt{y}}{ x+\sqrt {y}}$|+C

(last step from $\frac{x}{\sqrt y}= \sec \theta$)

Comment: `\sec`, `\tan`, `\csc`, `\cot` will give the trig functions typeset properly inside MathJax.

Comment: @arturo, thanks, edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the substitution advice "y" will go out of the integral as a constant the integration will concern another function of "u" variable that is not easy to integrate as the first one , I will recommend to you to go as x=cos(a) a trigonometric function is very flexible tool you can find your way to a form of integral with a multiplication of two trigonometric function then you can integrate by part ,sorry I don't know your mathematic level.this is as far as I can go

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).